# Changing User Control When Another Button in a User Control is Clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, caliburn.micro

This answer can be in either Prism and/or Caliburn.Micro. Changing user control in the main shell can be done with something like this:

**Prism**

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", uri);
```

**Caliburn.Micro**

```
ActivateItem(new ViewModel());
```

But my question is, how can you change the user control that is shown in the shellview upon clicking a button inside another user control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the exact same line (for Prism, at least) in any command anywhere. In case your're wondering how to get the `_regionManager` - just have it injected as constructor dependency.